# Drupal7 data in Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bigdata

I am trying to sync Drupal 7 with MongoDB using MongoDB module. When I add a node, the body (Description) field is saving in MySQL. Is there any way to add node body description field in MongoDB itself .?.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](http://spf13.com/post/getting-started-with-drupal-and-mongodb).

You have to be sure about migrating your fields to MongoDB, to do it you have to do some configuration on /sites/default/settings.php file like in the link.

```html
$Conf[‘field_storage_default’] = ‘mongodb_field_storage’;
```

Yo have to know, because of the original data "relationed", you can not build Views from MongoDB fields with default SQL Query backend, yo have to use [EFQ Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/efq_views)